# Change formula based on cell value excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to change the formula of cell B based on the value of cell A.
If the value in A is 2, i want the formula to be e^(-b*x) and otherwise it should be x^2.

I tried it with an IF-statement:

```
=IF(G2=2; [D2*EXP(-(L2*E2))];[E2*E2])
```

But it does not work. Also, examples only use IF-statements to display text.
So i am wondering if what i would like to do is even possible.

Comment: the problem seems to be at the E2^2, use POWER(E2;2) or E2*E2

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but it still does not solve my issue. The error is get is: "The name that you entered is not valid" and then some reasons that could cause the error.

Comment: And without the square braces, it works on my LibreCalc like that =IF(G2=2; D2*EXP(-(L2*E2));POWER(E2;2))

Comment: Wy the minus sign in the exponent ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `[]`. On the docs when the value is between `[]` means optional.

Try this:

`=IF(G2=2;D2*EXP(-(L2*E2));E2*E2)`